# Android studio doesn't launch in Elementary OS (Freya)

Tags: linux, android-studio

Alright, so yesterday I was writing code in Android studio, and when I saw that the autocomplete function wasn't working properly, I did the "Invalidate and Restart" function, that closed the Android Studio. And now, when I try to start Android Studio, simply nothing happens, I can spam the shortcut like crazy, nothing pops up, nothing. I was working on a project so I really need this fixed ASAP, but Google offers no clues.

I'd really appreciate any clues or fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up reinstalling the OS after running into some more issues with removing and reinstalling the Studio a couple of times.